# Append html string to DOM without being rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `javascript` string container HTML,, something like:

```
var html = "&lt;h1&gt;Justification&lt;/h1&gt;";
```

how can I add this to the `DOM` with `jQuery` without being rendered?

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
<h1>Justification</h1>
```

**NOT**

**Justification**

Thank you

Comment: @middaparka var html = "&lt;h1&gt;Justification&lt;/h1&gt;"; and var html = "<h1>Justification</h1>";

Comment: `$("<div/>").html(escape(html))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is modify textContent instead of innerHTML of intended DOM element.

It can be done something like below

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.textContent = "<h1>Justification</h1>"
```

or if you're getting HTML escaped string as in your question then we first need to unescape it as below

```
var escapedText = "&lt;h1&gt;Justification&lt;/h1&gt;";

function unescapedText(escapedText) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = escapedText;
    return div.textContent;
}

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.textContent = unescapedText(escapedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

HI you can use something like this using jquery :

```
var html = "&lt;h1&gt;Justification&lt;/h1&gt;";
$("<div/>").html(html).val();
```

This work for me and will work for you too....